# adding meta info to contents and filter them

Tags: entities, meta-tags

the target is to be add a meta field for drupal custom content type. that meta tag should be selectable by user when adding a new article .

the meta field is meant for language . (e.g. English / Urdu). the content types should show which  belong to the specific meta tag. e.g. if user selects English then the articles marked with english meta tag show up only.

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Internationalization](https://drupal.org/project/i18n) module?

> This is a collection of modules to extend Drupal core multilingual
>   capabilities and be able to build real life multilingual sites. Some
>   features:
>
> - Taxonomy translation (both, per language terms and translatable terms)
> - Multilingual variables Multilingual blocks (control visibility per
>     language and translate title and content)
> - Language selection (when you switch the site language you'll see only the content for that
>     language)
> - Requires [Variable module](http://drupal.org/project/variable) 2.x (Drupal 7)
> - Read a complete
>     feature overview in the [Internationalization handbook: Building
>     multilingual sites](https://drupal.org/node/133977) .

If you dont want a full `i18n` site you can always just use a custom field or Taxonomy term and Views to build page lists of content tagged with that language.

Comment: thank you for the answer. while it seems very promising, but for the current requirement, it may be sufficient to add a custom field (dropdown) to the content fields. am searching for how to add a dropdown as a field type but yet to find something. can you guide in this regard

Comment: Hi, please read both https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/field-ui  and also https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/list